# How to capture the deleted records in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, publish-subscribe

I have a SQL Server(Ex. subscriber) which subscribes to another SQL Server(Ex. publisher).

The new records are easy to deal with. But I do not know how to capture the deleted records in subscriber.

I can not modify the publisher, but I have full access to subscriber and the distribution server.

For Example:

```
record id100 inserted
record id100 processed by my program 
record id100 deleted(how can I capture this one, so my program can reprocess it again.)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I used a triger to solve this problem.